# Show that $ \Sigma (S^2 \times S^2) \simeq \Sigma (S^2 \vee S^2) \vee S^5$

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

There is the section of an argument in a topology textbook:

- $ S^2 \vee S^2$ is the 3-skeleton of $S^2 \times S^2$ (as in [CW-complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex))
- $ \Sigma (S^2 \times S^2) \simeq \Sigma (S^2 \vee S^2) \vee S^5$
- homotopy retraction $\Sigma (S^2 \times S^2) \to \Sigma (S^2 \vee S^2) $

Here $\Sigma$ is the [suspension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_(topology)) and we have that $\Sigma X = S^1 \wedge X$ :
$$ S^1 \wedge (S^2 \times S^2) \simeq  \big( S^1 \wedge ( S^2 \vee S^2 ) \big) \vee S^5$$
I guess the the question is about the relation between the cartesian product $\times$ and the [wedge sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum) $\vee$.

These spaces are difficult to visualize since the dimension count is $2 + 2 + 1 = 5$ dimensions.

Comment: "... and the smash product $\vee$" isn't the smash product usually denoted with $\wedge$?

Comment: and to be precise, $\Sigma$ actually refers to the [reduced suspension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_(topology)#Reduced_suspension)

Comment: Here is a brief explanation of that homotopy equivalence. According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301402/suspension-of-a-product-tricky-homotopy-equivalence) we have that $$LHS\simeq \Sigma S^2\vee\Sigma S^2\vee\Sigma(S^2\wedge S^2)\simeq \Sigma(S^2\vee S^2)\vee\Sigma S^4\simeq \Sigma(S^2\vee S^2)\vee S^5\simeq RHS$$