# the relation between well-pointed spaces and CW complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I was reading the second solution here:

[Suspension of a product - tricky homotopy equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301402/suspension-of-a-product-tricky-homotopy-equivalence/3473146#3473146) but the author said that the situation of well-pointed spaces is considered a more general situation than of $X$ and $Y$ being CW complexes.

Could someone clarify to me why this is correct please?

Comment: A CW-complex is well-pointed with respect to any of its points. Is that what you're interested in?

Comment: Any point $x \in X$ is in the interior of some $k$-cell, then show that $x \to X^{(k)}$ is a cofibration.

Comment: @Thorgott I am interested in more details (the proof that every well-pointed space is a CW-complex)

Comment: @ronno how can I show that?

Comment: Consider a small disk neighborhood $D$ of $x$ in the $k$-cell, now to extend homotopies, find an equivalence between $D$ and $D \cup_x x \times [0,1]$ rel $\partial D$ that takes $x$ to $(x, 1)$. One way to do this is to imitate the Alexander trick, at time $t$ map the disk of radius $t/2$ to the segment $x \times [0, t]$ and the annulus with inner radius $t/2$ to $D \setminus x$ by scaling the radius.

Comment: @Emptymind That's the opposite direction of what I said.

Comment: @Thorgott so I think I am interested in showing the equivalence between them then

Comment: There is no equivalence either. I don't understand what it is that you think I'm saying, because I think it was pretty clear.

Comment: @Thorgott I am not saying that you told me that there is an equivalence ...... I just understood wrongly that there is one ...... so you are saying now no, and the only correct direction is the direction you mentioned, am I right in my understanding?